# Flutter: Change Scroll Offset in a child through NavigationBar

Tags: flutter

I currently have a Homepage, which consists of a `Scaffold`, with a `bottomAppBar` for navigation:

[image: Navigation Bar]

The body has 5 pages, the first page is a feed, which consists of a `ListView` of Widgets.
What I want to do is same as Instagram has it:
when I scroll down the feed and  I click the Feed Button on the Navigation Bar, then I want the `ListView` to scroll back to the top automatically.

This is part of my code:

```
class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
  int _selectedIndex = 0;
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    body: [
      HomeFeed(),
      Page2(),
      ...
      ].elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      
    bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
      child: Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          IconButton(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.houseUser),
            onPressed: (){
              if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
                //add logic to make the HomeFeed ListView scroll up
              } else {
                 setState((){
                   _selectedIndex = 0;
                 });
              }
            },
          IconButton(
            icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.compass),
            onPressed: (){
              setState((){
                _selectedIndex = 1;
              });
            },
          ...
         ],
        ),
       ),  //BottomAppBar
       
    ), //Scaffold  
       
    }
```

I know that if I had the code of the HomeFeed inside the `Scaffold.body` then I could just use a `Scrollcontroller` and the `animateTo` method. The problem is that the Homefeed is another stateful widget and even though setState is called when clicking the feed icon, the HomeFeed widget is not rebuilding.
I tried defining a `Scrollcontroller` in the Homepage and pass it to the HomeFeed but it did not work.

Can anyone help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a `GlobalKey` for the state of the `HomeFeed` widget. Using this `GlobalKey` you can call the functions of the state of the `HomeFeed` widget.

Main code:

```
  GlobalKey<HomeFeedState> feedKey = new GlobalKey<HomeFeedState>(); // this is new

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: [
        HomeFeed(key: feedKey), // this is new
        Page3(),
      ].elementAt(_selectedIndex),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            IconButton(
              icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.houseUser),
              onPressed: (){
                if (_selectedIndex == 0) {
                  feedKey.currentState.jumpUp(); // this is new
                } else {
                  setState(() {
                    _selectedIndex = 0;
                  });
                }
              },
            ),
            IconButton(
              icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.compass),
              onPressed: (){
                setState(() {
                  _selectedIndex = 1;
                });
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ), //BottomAppBar
    );
  }
```

HomeFeed:

```
class HomeFeed extends StatefulWidget {
  final GlobalKey<HomeFeedState> key; // this is new
  HomeFeed({this.key}) : super(key: key); // this is new
  @override
  HomeFeedState createState() => HomeFeedState();
}

class HomeFeedState extends State<HomeFeed> {
  var _scrollController = new ScrollController();

  jumpUp() { // this will be called when tapped on the home icon
    _scrollController.animateTo(0,
        duration: Duration(seconds: 2), curve: Curves.ease);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        shrinkWrap: true,
        controller: _scrollController,
        itemCount: 100,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Container(
            height: 300,
            child: Card(
              child: Center(
                child: Text('$index'),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this (almost) solved the problem! The only issue which I have left is that HomeFeed and HomePage are in 2 different dart files. When I put the code in one file it works as expected, but if I have it in 2 files, then ´GlobalKey<HomeFeedState>´ in the HomePage file doesn't recognize HomeFeedState, even though I imported the HomeFeed file. Any idea how to solve this? I really want to to keep the 2 files sperated.

Comment: If you've defined the `HomeFeedState` as `_HomeFeedState`, just remove the '_'. @Losyres

Comment: You are right, the HomeFeedState was private. Great, thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

```
              class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
                @override
                _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
              }

              class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> with WidgetsBindingObserver {
                int _selectedIndex = 0;
                  Widget homeWidget  = HomeFeed();
                
                PageController pageController = PageController();
                @override
                Widget build(BuildContext context) {
                return Scaffold(
                  body: PageView(
                    controller: pageController,
                  
                    children: <Widget>[
                      homeWidget,
                      Second(),
                        ...
                    ],
                  ),
                    
                  bottomNavigationBar: BottomAppBar(
                    child: Row(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        IconButton(
                          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.houseUser),
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState((){
                             homeWidget = HomeFeed();
                              _selectedIndex = 0;
                              pageController.jumpToPage(0);
                            });
                          },
                        IconButton(
                          icon: FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.compass),
                          onPressed: (){
                            setState((){
                              _selectedIndex = 1;
                              pageController.jumpToPage(1);
                            });
                          },
                        ...
                      ],
                      ),
                    ),  //BottomAppBar
                    
                  ), //Scaffold  
                    
                  }
```

use  like this

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't solve the problem. The navigation worked well also without PageView. The problem is that when I am on the HomeFeed and I scroll down the feed, I want to just click on the HomeFeed symbol in the NavigationBar to have the feed automatically scroll back to the top.

Comment: If you want to  reset your homeFeed.  do this thing

Widget homeWidget = Homefeed() ;

on click of  bottom home then call 

setState((){
homeWidget = HomeFeed();
})


in body [
homeWidget,
page2(),
]